# Changing Labels in DetailVC from tableView

Tags: swift, label, tableview

I’m trying to make changes to a label in a DetailViewController, depending on which row we click:

[That is how my test App looks](http://subefotos.com/ver/?65ba467040cb9280e8ec49644fd156afo.jpg)

For example, if we click Ferrari I want to display:

```
“Wow , it's a beautiful red Ferrari of the year… blablabla..”
```

But if you click another instead:

```
“I’m the label of the…. car”
```

Essentially, one description for each car.

### How do I change the label?

**My code :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var valueToPass : String!

//crear un color
let medOrange: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.973, green: 0.388, blue: 0.173, alpha: 1)

var vehicleData : [String] = ["Ferrari 458" , "Lamborghini Murcielago" , "Bugatti Veyron", "Mercedes Benz Biome"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var nib = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    //Propiedades de la tableView
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = medOrange
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return vehicleData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as TableViewCell

    cell.lblCarName.text = vehicleData[indexPath.row]

    cell.imgCar.image = UIImage(named: vehicleData[indexPath.row])

    cell.backgroundColor = medOrange

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("Has seleccionado la celda #\(indexPath.row)!")

    //Obtener la label de la celda
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!

    valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel?.text

    performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailView", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "DetailView") {

        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

        vc.passedValue = valueToPass

    }  
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var passedValue : String!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblDetail: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imgDetail: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you did all well and the only part missing in your code is setting passedValue to label in your DetailViewController so just add the following in viewDidLoad method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    lblDetail.text = passedValue

}
```

EDITED:

To pass description to DetaliViewContorller you have to store it somehow first and the best way to do it is by declaring a struct that holds both name and description

```
struct Vehicle {

    var vehicleName : String
    var vehicleDescription : String
}
```

Then your vehicleData array should contain objects of type Vehicle

```
var vehicleData : [Vehice] = [Vehicle(vehicleName : "Ferrari 458",vehicleDescription : "Ferrari desc" ), //Add all vehicles like this...]
```

And finally passedValue must be initialized like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   valueToPass = vehicleData[indexPath.row].vehicleDescription

   performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailView", sender: self)

}
```

Comment: Thx for answer my friend. That's ok I thing , but how to load the content of lblDetail??
  Perhaps with array with descriptions as "Stranger" said
How to do it?? :S

Comment: it makes very much sense now bro
 the only thing i didnt understand its where to initialize this:

Comment: valueToPass = vehicleData[indexPath.row].vehicleDescription

Must I do it in detailVC?

Comment: @FactorJose no you must do this in first viewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method (and clear everything else). Also in cellForRowAtIndexPath lblCarName text shoud be set by getting vehicleName cell.lblCarName.text = vehicleData[indexPath.row].vehicleName

Comment: You're a boss @zellb
It's almost perfectly running

I have one error:

I run simulator, when I click the first car the label is empty,
now i go back, click second car : the label display the information of the first one,
go back again, click the third and the label display the information of de second.. :S

Comment: @FactorJose Check the edited answer and look if didSelectedRowAtIndexPath has the same implementation and show me  vehicleData if not working again

Comment: Oh man!!! Thx so much !!!
Now its running at 100 %

do u have Twitter to follow u?

Answer (score 0):

its Simple do the following steps:

1. add one more array with the details text in the details view controller.
2. when user click on the row you need to get the index.row and pass it to your details view controller.
3. retrive data from your number 1 step array using index path.
4. add it to your Lable.
5. and must set your Lable.text in the ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thx for answering bro.

How would you do the array with the descriptions??

Comment: as you have mentioned. all the desciptions are for each car. add all descriptions text in array and if any cars have no description still leave blank space and add next in to array..

Comment: Once I have the array wrote:
How to associate this array to lblDetail first?

Comment: just you will have to get the index.row for click car row and pass this value to detailsviewcontroller. and in the details view you can retrieve data from new added description array using index path.row.